# NPOI 2.6.0-rc-3 with .net framework 4.8.1 for updating .xlsx - losses charts in excel file

Tags: c#, .net-4.8, npoi

I use NPOI 2.6.0-rc-3 with .net framework 4.8.1 for updating .xlsx file. Excel file includes charts with it. excel file get crashed and after saving. After recovering the same file it losses charts in excel.

```
Used the following code.
         
            XSSFWorkbook wb1 = null;


            using (var file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                wb1 = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

                file.Close();


                //Updated the cell values here

                using (var file2 = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                {
                    
                    wb1.Write(file2);
                    file2.Close();
                }
                

            }


Please help regrading this matter
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify the cells out of the using block (you dont need to keep the file open to modify the IWorkbook) and then save it using a diferent stream:

```
        IWorkbook wb1 = null;
        using (FileStream file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            wb1 = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        }

        //Updated the cell values here

        using (FileStream fileWrite = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            wb1.Write(fileWrite);
        }
```